# Trigonometry difficulty while solving vectors in 3 dimensions

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, vectors, euclidean-geometry, 3d

There is a formula of the angle (say, $\phi$) between a plane $\pi$ and a line $l$:

$$\phi=\sin^{-1}\frac{\vec{b}.\vec{n}}{|\vec{b}||\vec{n}|}\tag{1}$$

Where $l$ is parellel to $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector to $\pi$ from the origin
[image]

I tried to convert it into a 2D problem and derive it in the following manner:

Let the required angle be $\theta$

The equation of line is $\vec{r}=\vec{a}+\lambda\vec{b}$ and that of the plane is $\vec{r}.\hat{n}=d$

**Note: Here $\hat{n}$ is the normal unit vector to plane from the origin**

In the figure, $AB$ lies on the plane $\pi$ and $\vec{AE}$ lies on $l$

$\vec{CB}$ is perpendicular distance to the plane from the origin, and is equal to $d\hat{n}$, also let $\vec{BE}=d\hat{n}$ where $d$ is some real number

Let's drop a perpendicular from a point $D$ to a point $A$ on the plane such that $AB$ and $DC$ are parallel

Clearly, the angle $BDC$ will also be $\theta$. Let $BD=x$

Then $BC=x\sin\theta$

$$x=\frac{d}{\sin\theta}$$

the angle $ABD$ will also be $\theta$

Therefore, $AB=BD\sin\theta$

$AB=d$

Now, we have to find the angle between $l$ and $AB$

Considering $l$ is parallel to $\vec{b}$, let $\vec{AE}=\lambda\vec{b}$

$\lambda\vec{b}.d\hat{k}=\lambda|\vec{b}|d\cos\theta$

for some real number $\lambda$ and
$\hat{k}$ being unit normal vector in the direction $\vec{AB}$

$$\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac{\vec{b}.\hat{k}}{|\vec{b}|}$$

Now, we can also say $$\frac{\vec{b}.\vec{n}}{|\vec{b}||\vec{n}|}=\frac{\vec{b}.K\hat{n}}{K|\vec{b}|}=\frac{\vec{b}.\hat{n}}{|\vec{b}|}$$

Where $K$ is the magnitude of $\vec{n}$

That should mean from $1$:

$$\sin^{-1}\frac{\vec{b}.\hat{n}}{|\vec{b}|}=\cos^{-1}\frac{\vec{b}.\hat{k}}{|\vec{b}|}$$
(I realised that this result wouldn't have required this long derivation only after deriving it.)

Question $1$: Is the derivation so far correct?

Question $2$: How to express $$\cos^{-1}\frac{\vec{b}.\hat{k}}{|\vec{b}|}$$ as $$\sin^{-1}\frac{\vec{b}.\hat{n}}{|\vec{b}|}?$$( It is known that $\hat{k}$ is perpendicular to $\hat{n}$)

Comment: Hint: $|\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}+\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}|^2=|\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}|^2+|\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}|^2\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. We can say that $\hat{k}.\hat{n}=0$, but I still don't recall how to express $\hat{k}$ in terms of $\hat{n}$

Comment: Was my answer below helpful?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP does not respond.

Comment: @KurtG. First of all, thanks for your answer. Second, I am still thinking about your answer, so responding prematurely doesn't make sense.....

Comment: Ok. In your notation $\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac{\vec{b}.\hat{k}}{|\vec{b}|}\,.$ Using $\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$ and my answer it should follow that $\theta=\sin^{-1}\frac{\vec{b}.\hat{n}}{|\vec{b}|}\,.$

Answer (score 1):

Because $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ and
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{\vec{b}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}}{|\vec{b}|}
$$
we only have to show that
$$
\frac{(\vec{b}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{k}})^2}{|\vec{b}|^2}+\frac{(\vec{b}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{n}})^2}{|\vec{b}|^2}=1
$$
holds. This follows from the fact that $\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}$ are orthogonal unit vectors by which the squared length of
$\vec{b}$ is equal to the sum of the squares of the components of $\vec{b}$
given in the basis $\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\,.$
If you remember how to get those components from projections this
means nothing else than
$$
|\vec{b}|^2=(\vec{b}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{k}})^2+(\vec{b}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{n}})^2\,.
$$